# Crear tabla a través de resultados de ciclo for con python

Tags: python, bucle-for, print, timeseries

no soy experto en el tema, pero quisiera saber si es posible crear una tabla con los resultados (que son de tipo serie) que se obtienen al pasar por el ciclo for, actualmente con el print, se genera una serie de datos que se va repitiendo por el for hacia abajo, pero quisiera ver si los valores se pueden ir agregando al lado como columnas.

```
      #Forecast
      #ES
        mod_es = SimpleExpSmoothing(df2[columnas[i]]).fit(optimized=True)
        df2['ES']=mod_es.fittedvalues
        pred_es=mod_es.forecast(12)
        pred_es.index= pd.to_datetime(pred_es.index, format='%Y/%m/%D')
        pred_es.index = pred_es.index.strftime('%Y/%m')
        expo_s=pd.concat([df2['ES'],pred_es])
    
      #Holt
        mod_Holt = Holt(df2[columnas[i]]).fit(optimized=True)
        df2['Holt']=mod_Holt.fittedvalues
        pred_Holt=mod_Holt.forecast(12)
        pred_Holt.index= pd.to_datetime(pred_Holt.index, format='%Y/%m/%D')
        pred_Holt.index = pred_Holt.index.strftime('%Y/%m')
        expo_Holt=pd.concat([df2['Holt'],pred_Holt])
    
        EXP2 = pd.concat([df2[columnas[i]],pred_es,pred_Holt])
        P=pd.DataFrame(EXP2, columns=[i])
        P[i] = pd.Series(EXP2, dtype="float64")
    
        EXP2 = pd.concat([df2[columnas[i]],pred_es,pred_Holt])
    
        print(EXP2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Cuando utilizas la función `pd.concat()`, puedes elegir si deseas concatenar filas o columnas con el argumento `axis` (Filas = 0, es la opción por defecto. Columnas = 1)

Teniendo el siguiente ejemplo

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 2]], columns=['letra', 'numero'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['perro', 'firulais'], ['gato', 'peludo']], columns=['animal', 'nombre'])
```

Tenemos 2 dataframes que se muestran de la siguiente forma

df1:

```
   letra    numero
0   a         1
1   b         2
```

df2:

```
    animal  nombre
0   perro   firulais
1   gato    peludo
```

Para concatenar las columnas del segundo dataframe al primero, utilizamos la siguiente línea de código:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

El resultado es:

```
   letra    numero  animal  nombre
0   a         1     perro   firulais
1   b         2     gato    peludo
```

Como no pusiste un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) no puedo resolver tu problema específico, pero en general, si utilizas el `axis = 1` vas a adjuntar columnas en lugar de filas